# How to take the result of a Linq CompiledQuery

Tags: linq, performance

Linq and compiled queries

This is my code:

I need to associated the value of a properties `a.Valu`e to a `Literal.Text` property.

Any idea how to do it?
Thanks for your valuable help!

```
                using (var context = new CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel())
                {
                context.CmsOptions.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
                var query = CompiledQuery.Compile<CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel, IQueryable<CmsOption>>
                    (ctx => from a in ctx.CmsOptions where a.OptionId == 7 select a);

               uxHeaderIncluder.Text = // What I do here?; 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at these examples: 
http://www.blog.ingenuitynow.net/15+Minutes+On+LINQ+Compiled+Queries.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx

The core of the approach is to spesify the input type(s) in the Compile method call.
Your compile call should be something like this:

```
CompiledQuery.Compile<CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel,string,string, IQueryable<CmsOption>>
((ctx,str1,str2)=>from a in ctx.CmsOptions where a.OptionId == 7 && /* use str1 and str2 params here */ select a);
```